# node.js serving content slowly, but then randomly go back to fast

Tags: node.js

The situation is simple. I'm testing a simple node.js server but my browsers says it takes ~200ms to receive the content (wich is far too long, considering my server is local). The code:

```
var http = require('http');


http.createServer(function(request, response) {

    console.log('>> '+request.url);

    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    response.write('just no! because no!');
    response.end();

}).listen(80);


console.log('server running at port 80');
```

I run it in ubuntu with the command `sudo node test.js`.

As you can see, the response is very tiny. But then, sometimes when I change the response it randomly chooses to go back to fast and takes ~9ms or so. I tested in chrome's inspect element and in firefox's firebug. I couldn't find a pattern at all, nor an explanation. What's happening, folks? thanks (:

Comment: by the way, the server is in a local virtual machine (vmware)...could it be the problem?

Comment: Have you tried to set the content lenght? And yes, virtualisation could be a problem.

Comment: Local to the your internal network or local to your machine? What does it do if you use `ab` (apache benchmark) from the same VM?

Comment: Don't do apache benchmark with this code, console.log would take a lot cycles

Comment: content-lenght header was of no help. i guess i'll just test apache in the server and compare or run this code with windows binary of nodejs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally just try to aviod console log statements. Anyway I believe virtualization might be a problem here, I have been using Node in production and have never seen such issues.
You might want to test your code with using some performance related tools, in case does not helps get in touch with your admin.